# MySQL replication - writing to intermediary server breaks it

Tags: php, mysql

I have this topology:

A->B->C

Replication is one-way. Binlogs are format type 'ROW'. Server A is ultimate master and has read/write operations going on. Server B reads the binlogs from A but nothing writes to the local DB. Server C reads the binlogs from Server B, but applications also attempt to read/write to it. Now I know this is full of potentially disastrous issues, but I'm going to pick one problem to fixate on. This is a temporary solution to migrate data to another server and both ends need to be usable for a short period while everything is pointed over to C.

Imagine Server A and Server C independently process some records in a queue. When they are done, they delete the queue record from the queue table. Server A's records replicate to C without issue. Server C processes the records and deletes them. Now Server A attempts to process those same records and deletes them.

The binlog now references rows to delete that no longer exist on Server C and replication breaks.

I suppose switching to binlog format 'MIXED' would help here. I think the better solution would be to make each server process queue records only applicable to that server, but the application isn't built to do it yet..

Would binlog format MIXED be a panacea here?

Comment: You cannot have any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations take place on *any* server that is not the master. Otherwise, you will lose consistency, queries from the binlog will potentially fail, and then replication will halt.

Comment: Thank you @Sammitch. Sometimes the truth hurts. I guess that means replication is only useful for reading and having a hot backup server

Comment: Are the servers all the same major release of MySQL?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Actually, no. A is 5.5, B is 5.1, C is 5.5. That's a good point. Now imagine we go with master-master replication.. The problem doesn't get any better. Imagine Server A and B are master-master. Break the network link between them. Delete a row from Server A. Delete the same row from Server B. Re-establish the network link. Replication is broken because the row that each side referenced won't exist when the binary log is read and replication will stop... right?